# How to get a specific date in the current year

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

Suppose the current year is 2014; then I want get the date `2014-06-30`, if the current year is 2015 then I want `2015-06-30`

I tried `date('Y');` but it is just giving current year.

Comment: Why has this received 3 upvotes? It's a poor question which can be answered very easily by the documentation...

Comment: I don't understand what you want to know. You have already found the answer to get the current year.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use:

```
date("Y-06-30")
```

Answer (score 2):

Demo : https://eval.in/103028

try:

```
echo date("Y-06-30");
```

OUTPUT:

```
2014-06-30
```

See date documentation: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the rest of your required date to your `date()` function as follow

```
echo date('Y') . '-06-30';
//output 2014-06-30
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
date("Y-06-30");
```

`Y` will be the your year and rest will same.

Where y is `A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits` for more Info : [Date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score -2):

You need to put like below code:

```
$d = date('Y');
$data = $d."-06-30";   
echo $data;
```